# Reading a number in a specific position

Tags: mysql

I have a table having a field of telephone numbers. I need to update the "districtname" field in function of the 3rd number from left.

```
 UPDATE mytable
 SET districtname =
 CASE
    WHEN the3rdnumberfromleft = '8' THEN 'Mycountryname'
    ELSE ''
 END
```

How can I set the condition to read the number in that specific position?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `LIKE` with wildcard character in MySql

```
UPDATE mytable 
   SET districtname = 'yourDesiredName'
WHERE telephone LIKE '__8%'
```

**Explanation:**

`__8%` will match any telephone number that has number `8` at third position from left.

Note there are two `_` (underscore) characters before `8` meaning match first `two` (one for each) to any character

And then comes `8` so it will only match for `8`

And then comes `%` meaning match any characters afterwards.

For more on this, refer [this link](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-comparison-functions.html)

Answer (score 0):

If I read your question correctly you're looking to update only some of the rows in your table. If that's true, try this.

```
 UPDATE mytable 
    SET districtname = 'Mycountryname'
  WHERE SUBSTRING(LTRIM(telephone),3,1) = '8'
```

This will choose only the rows with the 8 as you mentioned. I threw in LTRIM to cope with the situation where your telephone number might have spaces before it. You don't need that if you're sure all your telephone numbers are left-justified.

If the telephone number is stored in an integer field, this will still work because MySQL implicitly converts integers you use in as if they were strings.